# How to show usernames using GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to show usernames instead of userid's in a mysql query that users GROUP_CONCAT. The following query works but shows user id's. How can I show usernames instead?

The query

```
SELECT p.user_name, p.user_id, up.file, GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid)
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
GROUP BY up.file
```

Results

```
user_name | user_id  |    file     |   GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid)

Peter         5         pic_1.jpg               2,5
Mary          6         pic_2.jpg               6
julian        2         pic_3.jpg              (null)
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(c.usernames)`?

Comment: SELECT p.user_name, p.user_id, up.file, GROUP_CONCAT(c.userid),GROUP_CONCAT(c.user_name) as username
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
GROUP BY up.file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the users table one more time, and get the usernames from there:

```
SELECT p.user_name, p.user_id, up.file, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.user_name)
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.userid
GROUP BY up.file
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `tbl_users` has user names.  If so, use that for the `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT up.file, GROUP_CONCAT(p.username)
FROM tbl_uploads up LEFT JOIN
     tbl_users p
     ON up.user_id = p.user_id LEFT JOIN
     tbl_collab c
     ON up.file = c.file
GROUP BY up.file;
```

Note I removed `p.username` from the `SELECT`.  In general, in an aggregation query, all columns/expressions should either be in the `GROUP BY` or arguments to aggregation functions.